# How to find the cause for an undescriptive TypeScript compiler error?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, crash, tsc, react-hook-form

I get a strange compiler error. It states: `RangeError: Value undefined out of range for undefined options property undefined`.

My feeling so far is, that the compiler runs internally into a loop and fills up a `Map` until it is full. My best guess is, that this is connected to some faulty type declaration in our own code base.

My problem is, that the compiler is not telling which part of my code base is the issue for this problem and happened after a package update. So I don't see any hint which specific part of our code base is the root cause for this. How can I convince TypeScript to tell me this?

The whole stack trace looks like this:

```
$ yarn tsc
yarn run v1.22.4
$ /myProject/app/node_modules/.bin/tsc
/myProject/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:90679
                throw e;
                ^RangeError: Value undefined out of range for undefined options property undefined
    at Map.set (<anonymous>)
    at recursiveTypeRelatedTo (/myProject/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:50962:30)
    at isRelatedTo (/myProject/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:50543:34)
    at checkTypeRelatedTo (/myProject/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:50229:26)
    at isTypeRelatedTo (/myProject/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:50192:24)
    at isTypeSubtypeOf (/myProject/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:49480:20)
    at /myProject/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:47289:90
    at Object.some (/myProject/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:658:25)
    at _loop_14 (/myProject/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:47289:45)
    at removeStringLiteralsMatchedByTemplateLiterals (/myProject/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:47294:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**Background**

This happened after I upgraded [react-hook-form](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form) from version 6 to 7, with no other changes to the code base.

I tried already the following (all with the same outcome):

- Updating TypeScript to the newest 4.3.X version
- Updating to react-hook-form 7.0.0 (instead of the latest)
- It is reproducible on another machine
- Deleted node_modules
- Run `tsc -b --verbose`

**Side notes**

- The compiling takes long and eats a lot of memory before that error message appears.
- When I start the project in dev mode, it is actually starting and showing the website for a moment, but then switches to that same error message.

Comment: Are you allowed to share reproducable example?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Sadly not possible :-/ Its also a bigger project.

Comment: This is weird and seems to be a Typescript error. No matter your type definitions it should not happen (provided they are valid Typescript).
If you are using VS Code I would suggest to start looking into ts-server logs: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Getting-logs-from-TS-Server-in-VS-Code.md and see if the crash happens there are as well.

Comment: You can always enable debugging and attach the debugger. You have line numbers in your stack trace of where to set breakpoints or just take a peek in the code without the debugger to get an idea. Also, I'm not familiar with react-hook-form, but the stack trace mentions `recursiveTypeRelatedTo`, and the issue tracker for that project has V7 issues hit when searching the repo for "recursive", "circular", etc. I didn't look closely at their relevance, but they may still be relevant even if they're already closed.

Comment: I'm only getting a vague recollection of a similar problem I once had, but I might be able to remember more details if you respond...


I think I recall seeing this error if I tried to add a key to a TS array where the key didn't already exist. Something like:

`let a = []; a["myKey"] = "value";`

Doing anything like that?

Comment: It may be a node problem. They have an open issue on that type of error [https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37320](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/37320)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the exact same error on running `tsc` (both on snowpack and stand-alone).

In my case, it was caused by **"Circular Dependency"** issue.

I used the *indexed access type* in a specific part of the newly added code, and the file in which the object type is defined and the file in which the property type is defined are separated and referenced.

So, I changed the code that used the *indexed access type* to the actual property type.

So the error no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty desriptive (or it isn't)? It Looks like you have (or library that you are using) some kind of infinite loop somewhere.

`Map` can store up to `16777216` (`2^24`) values, after you store this amount and try to add 1 more, you will get this weird `RangeError`.

Here is example how you can re-create this error (wait around `10s`):

```js
const testMap = new Map()

Array.from(
  { length: Math.pow(2, 24) },
  (_, i) => testMap.set(i, 'x')
)

console.log(testMap.get(16777215)) // last value, no error
testMap.set(Math.pow(2, 24) + 1, 'x') // error will occur
```

It's hard to say how solve you exact problem without your entire code, but I would do something like this:

1. Find all `Map` declarations and comment them,
2. (optional) error should disappear, app might stop working,
3. Uncomment `Map` declarations 1 by 1 and check after which one you will get `RangeError`.

If error won't disappear after this, it's probably case with 1 of libraries that you recently updated. In this case the only way to solve this, might be revert project to last working version and apply changes step by step meanwhile looking at outcome.

### Additionaly

What's even more interesting, if you will treat standard `Object` as a "Map" you can store up to `2^32 - 1` values ([Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)).

Here is example how to re-create this error (wait around `10s`, might crash earlier, is up to **RAM** and **Browser**):

```js
const testObj = {}

Array.from(
  { length: Math.pow(2, 32) - 1 },
  (_, i) => testObj[i] = i
)

console.log(testObj[Math.pow(2, 32) - 1]) // last value, no error
testObj[Math.pow(2, 32)] // RangeError: Invalid array length
```

Alternative example of above:

```js
Array.from({ length: Math.pow(2, 32) }) // RangeError
```

Comment: Yes the error itself is descriptive for sure. The challenge is that it seems to happen inside of the TypeScript compiler. My latest guess is that there is a bug in the TypeScript compiler (even if my code is invalid, it should fail more descriptive and with a hint of the file/line). If this is the case, the TSC bug needs to be located and fixed or I need to find the syntax in my source code that is triggering it.

Comment: Also the exact `Map` that is failing is known from the trace. Its just a bit scary to try to debug the whole TS compiler ;-)

Comment: @flori Hard to believe that this is TS bug itself. Did you tried desperate things, like removing `yarn` and replacing it with `npm`, reinstalling `node_modules` ect?